# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error, property 'when' of undefined Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been researching and trying to figure out this error for 2days now and Still no luck.
To begin I new to angular, and I have following this tutorial : http://jphoward.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/end-to-end-web-app-in-under-an-hour/

Every was going well until my grid was not filling with data. So I decided to make minor changes to code and now I have ran into this error.

in my js file:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("Myapp", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).
    config([function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'list.html', controller: 'ListCtrl' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);


MyApp.factory('Myapp', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/Myapp/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { 
        method: 'PUT' } });
});


MyApp.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'ds72', function ($scope, Myapp) {
    $scope.todos = Myapp.query();
}]);
```

can some one please explain to me what i am doing wrong?

PS: These are all my Scripts

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like that

```
var MyApp = angular.module("Myapp", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).
    config(['$routeProvider',  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'list.html', controller: 'ListCtrl' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);
```

you must add the name of the provider to inject when you use the array declaration

```
.config(['$routeProvider'/*must be the exact name*/, function(route/*get the $routeProvider value*/) {}])
//equivalent as
.config(function($routeProvider) {})
```

Comment: I think you are right!.. but then again this leads on to the next error lol.. now I am getting : Error: $resource:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter .. do you have any Idea??

Comment: mmh, try to call the Myapp.update method instead of Myapp.query in your controller

Comment: so is the the $routeProvider in my above code the service Name??? so if i sound a bit dumb but i am dummy in angular

Comment: yes ^^ in your code it's $routeProvider, i changed that in my sample, it was too general.

so, what's about your config error? have you try to change Myapp.query to Myapp.update in your controller?

Comment: Actually it works.. gives me a blank list of data tho ....  just an empty grid of data

Comment: can you show me the calling? when you call the update method, do you send the parameters like " MyApp.update({ id:/*the Id*/ }, /*object to update*/) "

Comment: oh I just call my update method as it is.. e.g MyApp.update();..i don't put anything in the parameters ... hmm

Comment: if you call the update method is that you need to update something, so you need to pass some parameters ^^.
however, without the complete source code i cant help you anymore

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but is is how I am calling  the update method:     MyApp.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'myapp', function ($scope, $routeParams, myapp) {
    var a = myapp.get({ id:$routeParams.id });
    $id = a.id;
    $scope.todos = myapp.update({ id: $id }, a);